why getting parameter is not valid when dragging the custom progressbar to the form1 designer?
it was working fine first time when i dragged the custom progressbar to the form1 designer from the toolbox.  but now each time i try to drag it i get the exception error message.
and i didn't change anything.
link for the code where i took it from.
https://github.com/ukushu/TextProgressBar/blob/master/TextProgressBar.cs
here is an image screenshot showing the error message:

and the code
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Graphics == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    Graphics g = e.Graphics;

    DrawProgressBar(g);

    DrawStringIfNeeded(g);
}

line 134 is:
DrawStringIfNeeded(g);

and
private void DrawStringIfNeeded(Graphics g)
{
    if (VisualMode != ProgressBarDisplayMode.NoText)
    {
        string text = _textToDraw;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            SizeF len = g.MeasureString(text, TextFont);

            Point location = new Point((Width / 2) - (int)len.Width / 2, (Height / 2) - (int)len.Height / 2);

            g.DrawString(text, TextFont, _textColourBrush, location);
        }
    }
}

line 165 is:
g.DrawString(text, TextFont, _textColourBrush, location);

and the full code , it's a bit long but might be needed:
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public enum ProgressBarDisplayMode
{
    NoText,
    Percentage,
    CurrProgress,
    CustomText,
    TextAndPercentage,
    TextAndCurrProgress
}

public class CustomProgressBar : ProgressBar
{
    [Description("Font of the text on ProgressBar"), Category("Additional Options")]
    public Font TextFont { get; set; } = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, 14, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic);

    private SolidBrush _textColourBrush = (SolidBrush)Brushes.Black;
    [Category("Additional Options")]
    public Color TextColor
    {
        get
        {
            return _textColourBrush.Color;
        }
        set
        {
            _textColourBrush.Dispose();
            _textColourBrush = new SolidBrush(value);
        }
    }

    private SolidBrush _progressColourBrush = (SolidBrush)Brushes.LightGreen;
    [Category("Additional Options"), Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    public Color ProgressColor
    {
        get
        {
            return _progressColourBrush.Color;
        }
        set
        {
            _progressColourBrush.Dispose();
            _progressColourBrush = new SolidBrush(value);
        }
    }

    private ProgressBarDisplayMode _visualMode = ProgressBarDisplayMode.Percentage;
    [Category("Additional Options"), Browsable(true)]
    public ProgressBarDisplayMode VisualMode
    {
        get
        {
            return _visualMode;
        }
        set
        {
            _visualMode = value;
            Invalidate(); // Redraw component after change value from VS Properties section
        }
    }

    private string _text = string.Empty;

    [Description("If it's empty, % will be shown"), Category("Additional Options"), Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    public string CustomText
    {
        get
        {
            return _text;
        }
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            Invalidate(); // Redraw component after change value from VS Properties section
        }
    }

    private string _textToDraw
    {
        get
        {
            string text = CustomText;

            switch (VisualMode)
            {
                case ProgressBarDisplayMode.Percentage:
                    text = _percentageStr;
                    break;
                case ProgressBarDisplayMode.CurrProgress:
                    text = _currProgressStr;
                    break;
                case ProgressBarDisplayMode.TextAndCurrProgress:
                    text = $"{CustomText}: {_currProgressStr}";
                    break;
                case ProgressBarDisplayMode.TextAndPercentage:
                    text = $"{CustomText}: {_percentageStr}";
                    break;
            }

            return text;
        }
    }

    private string _percentageStr => $"{(int)((float)Value - Minimum) / ((float)Maximum - Minimum) * 100} %";

    private string _currProgressStr => $"{Value}/{Maximum}";

    public CustomProgressBar()
    {
        Value = Minimum;
        FixComponentBlinking();
    }

    private void FixComponentBlinking()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Graphics == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Graphics g = e.Graphics;

        DrawProgressBar(g);

        DrawStringIfNeeded(g);
    }

    private void DrawProgressBar(Graphics g)
    {
        Rectangle rect = ClientRectangle;

        ProgressBarRenderer.DrawHorizontalBar(g, rect);

        rect.Inflate(-3, -3);

        if (Value > 0)
        {
            Rectangle clip = new Rectangle(rect.X, rect.Y, (int)Math.Round(((float)Value / Maximum) * rect.Width), rect.Height);

            g.FillRectangle(_progressColourBrush, clip);
        }
    }

    private void DrawStringIfNeeded(Graphics g)
    {
        if (VisualMode != ProgressBarDisplayMode.NoText)
        {
            string text = _textToDraw;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
                SizeF len = g.MeasureString(text, TextFont);

                Point location = new Point((Width / 2) - (int)len.Width / 2, (Height / 2) - (int)len.Height / 2);

                g.DrawString(text, TextFont, _textColourBrush, location);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            _textColourBrush?.Dispose();
            _progressColourBrush?.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}


You cannot use Graphics.Drawstring() in this context (UserPaint, not supported by the underlying Control), you have to use TextRenderer.DrawText() -- Remove this thing: Graphics g = e.Graphics;, totally useless (looks really bad when inspecting the code)

BTW, I'd suggest to override WndProc and handle WM_PAINT, instead of overriding OnPaint / OnPaintBackground, as shown here: How to show the progress percentage in the middle center of a ProgressBar? (I think you probably asked that question) -- BTW2, a null object is never passed to OnPaint / OnPaintBackground. It might represent an infinite clipping Region (rare, edge case)

Code is good and runs without trouble on my machine.  Something is wrong with the Graphics object somehow, maybe this

@HansPassant From what I see here, it cannot work correctly. The ProgressBar is really a thin wrapper. It doesn't handle paint events. That goes to the base class (Control). It might work once; after that, when GDI+ has used the hDC, this graphic context can be nullptr (it could also affect the underlying Win32 Control) <- not sure, I haven't tested it, but it's easy to verify, dropping more than one instance of the custom control, then deleting one instance, or add one instance, delete it, then try to add a new one without rebuilding

That's not accurate, Control is not involved.  ProgressBar is a native Windows component that paints by itself.  Nothing dramatic happens with ControlStyles.UserPaint.  If set then OnPaint() runs, if not then the WM_PAINT message is forwarded to the native window procedure.  https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,14162

@HansPassant Yes, of course the NativeWindow's WndProc (the LRESULT Callback installed by SetWindowLong) receives the message, but then it's going to forward it. You get to the Control class at some point (the ProgressBar class does not handle paint stuff). When you get to PaintWithErrorHandling(), the hDC state can be compromised, i.e., not suitable to host font rendering. That's why I suggested to use TextRenderer, it doesn't care about that state

The designer throws that exception because you're using a disposed of or in the process of disposing brush when you drop instances.
private SolidBrush _textColourBrush = (SolidBrush)Brushes.Black;
[Category("Additional Options")]
public Color TextColor
{
    get
    {
        return _textColourBrush.Color;
    }
    set
    {
        _textColourBrush.Dispose();
        _textColourBrush = new SolidBrush(value);
    }
}

If you look carefully, the backing field here holds a reference to the static Brushes.Black brush and the setter disposes it before assigning the new value. That means the static Brushes.Black brush itself is gone application-wide and the default brush of the next instance is already disposed of and the DrawStringIfNeeded is using it to draw the text. You'll probably get some good instances until the Brushes.Black brush is get collected.
Replace the line:
g.DrawString(text, TextFont, _textColourBrush, location);

with
g.DrawString(text, TextFont, Brushes.Black, location);

and you'll get the same exception. The same applies to the ProgressColor property and you can no longer use Brushes.Black and Brushes.LightGreen brushes in your project. By the way, you should not dispose of any stock object (the static properties of the Brushes, Pens, SystemBrushes, SystemPens ...etc. classes).
To fix the current code, assign instances to the backing fields of these two properties.
// or assign the values in the ctor...
private SolidBrush _textColourBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
private SolidBrush _progressColourBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.LightGreen);

[Category("Additional Options")]
[DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Black")]
public Color TextColor
{
    get => _textColourBrush.Color;
    set
    {
        if (_textColourBrush == null || !_textColourBrush.Color.Equals(value))
        {
            _textColourBrush?.Dispose();
            _textColourBrush = new SolidBrush(value);
        }
    }
}

[Category("Additional Options")]
[DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "LightGreen")]
public Color ProgressColor
{
    get
    {
        return _progressColourBrush.Color;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_progressColourBrush == null || !_progressColourBrush.Color.Equals(value))
        {
            _progressColourBrush?.Dispose();
            _progressColourBrush = new SolidBrush(value);
        }
    }
}


The text renderer has nothing to do with the exception here. However, the TextRenderer is the best choice in this context.
The affected code:
private Color _textColor = Color.Black;
[Category("Additional Options")]
[DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Black")]
public Color TextColor
{
    get => _textColor;
    set
    {
        if (!_textColor.Equals(value))
        {
            _textColor = value;
            Invalidate();                    
        }
    }
}

private void DrawStringIfNeeded(Graphics g)
{
    if (VisualMode != ProgressBarDisplayMode.NoText &&
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_textToDraw))
    {
        TextRenderer.DrawText(g, _textToDraw, TextFont, ClientRectangle, TextColor,
            TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
    }
}


Side Note
The OnPaint method is continuously raised since you inherit from the ProgressBar control. This is not needed to draw a simple progress like this (no glow effect to draw for example). You can change this by pinvoke the SetWindowTheme function to disable the visual styles of the control so that it only redraws when needed.
protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    _ = SetWindowTheme(Handle, string.Empty, string.Empty);
}

[DllImport("uxtheme.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern int SetWindowTheme(IntPtr hwnd, string pszSubAppName, string pszSubIdList);


A couple of notes: you're absolutely right about the way the Brushes objects are treated here, but, as you may have noticed, the exception is always thrown when drawing the text, not when filling a rectangle, despite both stock brushes are mistreated and, since no [DefaultValue] is specified, both SolidBrushes are recreated as soon as the Control is initialized - The ProgressBarRenderer already uses DrawThemeBackground, and the underlying Control explicitly disables UserPaint. The DC where the GDI (not GDI+) function operates is not suitable to draw text with GDI+ (hence my comments)

Of course, since the felony has been committed at the Process / AppDomain level, you'll get an exception anyway, at some point, because a static resource has been destroyed, and (as you know :), when anything tries to use it again...

@Jimi Jimzi! Good day. As for the exception is always thrown when drawing the text, not when filling a rectangle ... Nop :) Assign some > 0 Value and comment out the drawing text part, you'll get the exception. In other words, that part does not through exception when you add a new instance because the initial value is 0. So, what if (Value > 0) { ... } block contains does not execute.

As for as you know :). The whole world knew about it already. Monster! :)

Oh crap, my bad. I made a faulty test. My Test changed the Color of the bar of the first instance of the Control, so I get an exception only when drawing the text. That was sloppy. Anyway, let me insist that using Graphics.DrawString() in this context is a bad idea. Also, I'd suggest - given the current functionality of the Control - not to derive from ProgressBar, just from Control (the Minimum, Maximum and Value Properties are easy to implement)
